# How to hide/remove tabBox grey borders in shiny R using CSS

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have shiny application with tabBox as shown below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(tags$style(".nav-tabs {
                      background-color: #006747;
                      }
                      
                      .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active:hover a, .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active a {
                      background-color: transparent;
                      border-color: transparent;
                      }
                      
                      .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active {
                      border-top-color: #990d5e;
                      }
                      
                      .content-wrapper {
                       background-color: #FFF;
                      }"),
                tabBox(
                  title = "First tabBox",
                  # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
                  id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
                  tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
                  tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
  )
  
  ))

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

[image]

I would like to hide/remove the grey border lines of the `tabBox` on all sides as indicated by arrows in the picture.

Could someone help which CSS class has to be used to make this change?

Comment: code have been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `box-shadow: none;` for class `.nav-tabs-custom`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(tags$style(".nav-tabs {
                      background-color: #006747;
                      }
                      
                      .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active:hover a, .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active a {
                      background-color: transparent;
                      border-color: transparent;
                      }
                      
                      .nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active {
                      border-top-color: #990d5e;
                      }
                      
                      .content-wrapper {
                       background-color: #FFF;
                      }
                      .nav-tabs-custom {
                          box-shadow: none;
                      }
                      "),
           tabBox(
             title = "First tabBox",
             # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
             id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
             tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
             tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
           )
           
  ))

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

[image: result]